# Framework file not found issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

i created a framework (Test.framework) with card.h and card.m file in Objective c

```
Test.h
#import<Test/card.h>
```

i try to import Test.framework in another project(Example.xcodeproj) getting error Test/card.h file not found ". 
what is wrong with my code?any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To link with framework you should add it to the xcproj (don't remember the name of the file sorry - it is that blue file of your project).

I am attaching a screenshot that shows where to add it.

Click on `+` button and locate your framework there to link it.
Also you will want to import or add a search path for your header files there:

[image]

[image]